# 'Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes" error when indexing a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, elasticsearch, bulk-load

This question is related to this other one:
[How can I read data from a list and index specific values into Elasticsearch, using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62459572/how-can-i-read-data-from-a-list-and-index-specific-values-into-elasticsearch-us/62460512?noredirect=1#comment110837766_62460512)

I have written a script to read a list ("dummy") and index it into Elasticsearch.
I converted the list into a list of dictionaries and used the "Bulk" API to index it into Elasticsearch.
The script used to work (check the attached link to the related question). But it is no longer working after adding "timestamp" and the function "initialize_elasticsearch".

So, what is wrong? Should I be using JSON instead of the list of dictionaries?

I have also tried using only 1 dictionary of the list. In that case there is no error but nothing gets indexed.

THIS IS THE ERROR

[image]

THIS IS THE LIST (dummy)

```
[
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 23.1",
    "Time(ms): 5.7",
    "Inference: corkscrew, bottle screw",
    "Score: 0.03125 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.05",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-M_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 29.3",
    "Time(ms): 10.8",
    "Inference: dragonfly, darning needle, devil's darning needle, sewing needle, snake feeder, snake doctor, mosquito hawk, skeeter hawk",
    "Score: 0.09375 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 56.8",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-L_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 45.6",
    "Time(ms): 31.0",
    "Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron",
    "Score: 0.09766 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.55",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v3_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 68.8",
    "Time(ms): 51.3",
    "Inference: ringlet, ringlet butterfly",
    "Score: 0.48047 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 121.8",
    "Time(ms): 101.2",
    "Inference: admiral",
    "Score: 0.59375 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.05",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v2_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 34.3",
    "Time(ms): 16.6",
    "Inference: lycaenid, lycaenid butterfly",
    "Score: 0.41406 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 14.4",
    "Time(ms): 3.3",
    "Inference: leatherback turtle, leatherback, leathery turtle, Dermochelys coriacea",
    "Score: 0.36328 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 14.5",
    "Time(ms): 3.0",
    "Inference: bow tie, bow-tie, bowtie",
    "Score: 0.33984 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
    "labels: imagenet_labels.txt ",
    "Model: inception_v1_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite ",
    "Image: insect.jpg ",
    "Time(ms): 21.2",
    "Time(ms): 3.6",
    "Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron",
    "Score: 0.17578 ",
    "TPU_temp(°C): 57.3",
]
```

THIS IS THE SCRIPT

```
import elasticsearch6  
from elasticsearch6 import Elasticsearch, helpers
import datetime
import re



ES_DEV_HOST = "http://localhost:9200/"
INDEX_NAME = "coral_ia" #name of index
DOC_TYPE = 'coral_edge'  #type of data



##This is the list
dummy = ['labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-S_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 23.1\n', 'Time(ms): 5.7\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: corkscrew, bottle screw\n', 'Score: 0.03125 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.05\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-M_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 29.3\n', 'Time(ms): 10.8\n', '\n', '\n', "Inference: dragonfly, darning needle, devil's darning needle, sewing needle, snake feeder, snake doctor, mosquito hawk, skeeter hawk\n", 'Score: 0.09375 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 56.8\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: efficientnet-edgetpu-L_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 45.6\n', 'Time(ms): 31.0\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron\n', 'Score: 0.09766 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.55\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v3_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 68.8\n', 'Time(ms): 51.3\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: ringlet, ringlet butterfly\n', 'Score: 0.48047 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v4_299_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 121.8\n', 'Time(ms): 101.2\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: admiral\n', 'Score: 0.59375 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.05\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v2_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 34.3\n', 'Time(ms): 16.6\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: lycaenid, lycaenid butterfly\n', 'Score: 0.41406 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 14.4\n', 'Time(ms): 3.3\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: leatherback turtle, leatherback, leathery turtle, Dermochelys coriacea\n', 'Score: 0.36328 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 14.5\n', 'Time(ms): 3.0\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: bow tie, bow-tie, bowtie\n', 'Score: 0.33984 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n', 'labels: imagenet_labels.txt \n', '\n', 'Model: inception_v1_224_quant_edgetpu.tflite \n', '\n', 'Image: insect.jpg \n', '\n', '*The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory*\n', 'Time(ms): 21.2\n', 'Time(ms): 3.6\n', '\n', '\n', 'Inference: pick, plectrum, plectron\n', 'Score: 0.17578 \n', '\n', 'TPU_temp(°C): 57.3\n', '##################################### \n', '\n']

#This is to clean data and filter some values
regex = re.compile(r'(\w+)\((.+)\):\s(.*)|(\w+:)\s(.*)')
match_regex = list(filter(regex.match, dummy))
match = [line.strip('\n') for line in match_regex]   
print("match list", match, "\n")


##Converts the list into a list of dictionaries
groups = [{}]

for line in match:
    key, value = line.split(": ", 1)
    if key == "labels":
        if groups[-1]:
            groups.append({})
    groups[-1][key] = value



"""
Initialize Elasticsearch by server's IP'
"""
def initialize_elasticsearch():
    n = 0
    while n <= 10:
        try:
            es = Elasticsearch(ES_DEV_HOST)
            print("Initializing Elasticsearch...")
            return es
        except elasticsearch6.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout as e:  ###elasticsearch
            print(e)
            n += 1
            continue
    raise Exception



"""
Create an index in Elasticsearch if one isn't already there
"""
def initialize_mapping(es):
    mapping_classification = {
        'properties': {
            'timestamp': {'type': 'date'},
            #'type': {'type':'keyword'}, <--- I have removed this 
            'labels': {'type': 'keyword'},
            'Model': {'type': 'keyword'},
            'Image': {'type': 'keyword'},
            'Time(ms)': {'type': 'short'},
            'Inference': {'type': 'text'},
            'Score': {'type': 'short'},
            'TPU_temp(°C)': {'type': 'short'}
        }
    }
    print("Initializing the mapping ...")  
    if not es.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
        es.indices.create(INDEX_NAME)
        es.indices.put_mapping(body=mapping_classification, doc_type=DOC_TYPE, index=INDEX_NAME)
        



def generate_actions():
    actions = {
        '_index': INDEX_NAME,
        'timestamp': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"'T'"%H:%M:%S")),
        '_type': DOC_TYPE,
        '_source': groups
        }

    yield actions
    print("Generating actions ...")
    #print("actions:", actions)
    #print(type(actions), "\n")



def main():
    es=initialize_elasticsearch()
    initialize_mapping(es)  
    
    try:
        res=helpers.bulk(client=es, index = INDEX_NAME, actions = generate_actions())
        print ("\nhelpers.bulk() RESPONSE:", res)
        print ("RESPONSE TYPE:", type(res))
        
    except Exception as err:
        print("\nhelpers.bulk() ERROR:", err)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

THIS IS THE CODE WHEN TESTING WITH ONLY 1 DICTIONARY

```
regex = re.compile(r'(\w+)\((.+)\):\s(.*)|(\w+:)\s(.*)')
match_regex = list(filter(regex.match, dummy))
match = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in match_regex]   #quita los saltos de linea
#print("match list", match, "\n")


features_wanted='ModelImageTime(ms)InferenceScoreTPU_temp(°C)'
match_out = {i.replace(' ','').split(':')[0]:i.replace(' ','').split(':')[1] for i in match if i.replace(' ','').split(':')[0] in features_wanted}
```

-------------------EDIT-------------------------

No errors, but "Generating actions ..." is not being printed.

[image]

[image]

THIS IS THE MAPPING

[image]

THIS APPEARS WHEN I WANT TO SEE IF THE DATA WAS INDEXED

[image]

IT SEEMS THE DATA HAS BEEN INDEXED...

[image]

----------------------EDIT-----------------------

I modified the `generate_actions`

```
def generate_actions():
    return[{
        '_index': INDEX_NAME,
        '_type': DOC_TYPE,
        '_source': {
            "any": doc,
            "@timestamp": str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"'T'"%H:%M:%S")),}
        }
        for doc in groups]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This somewhat cryptic error msg is telling you that you need to pass single objects (instead of an array of them) to the bulk helpers.

So you need to rewrite your `generate_actions` fn like so:

```
def generate_actions():
    return [{
        'timestamp': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"'T'"%H:%M:%S")),
        '_index': INDEX_NAME,
        '_type': DOC_TYPE,
        '_source': doc
    } for doc in groups]      # <----- note the for loop here. `_source` needs
                              # to be the doc, not the whole groups list

    print("Generating actions ...")
```

Also, I'd recommend to remove the trailing whitespace from your key-value pairs when you construct the `groups`:

```
groups[-1][key] = value.strip()
```

Comment: No errors but nothing gets indexed. I added an EDIT. What could be wrong?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong ... It indexed just fine for me. I think you need to adjust the time filter in the upper right corner of Kibana...

Comment: Maybe is the version of elasticsearch? I am with 6.x.x

Comment: rather not. Did you check the time filter I mentioned? It's set for "Today".. Try extending it or try resetting your index pattern. Finally, try going to the Dev Tools section (where you got the mapping) and type `GET coral_ia/_search`

Comment: I extended the time filter from july 1 to july 10. When checking the Dev Tools...the data seems to be there.

Comment: I still cannot see anything in discover. When I do: ```GET coral_ia/_search/template``` I get:  ```"type": "parse_exception",reason": "request body or source parameter is required"```

Comment: My bad -- the suggestion was for 7.x. Try `GET coral_ia/coral_edge/_search`

Comment: Dev Tools shows the data. But Discover nothing. I am using Windows.

Comment: it is the "timestamp". But I do not know what to put instead.

Comment: Reset your index patterns.

Comment: I mean, this line is wrong: ```'@timestamp':  str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"'T'"%H:%M:%S")),``` When I remove it from the ```generate_actions``` and from the  ```initialize_mapping``` Everything works. But there is no timestamp.

Comment: That one's perfectly fine. Then change your time filter dropdown in the top right corner. Your screenshot says that the selection is 2 days... Alternatively, try this: `str(datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat())` or `str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())`

Comment: Nope. I changed the time filter to "this week" and I tested the code you sent. :(

Comment: It was the timestamp. It has to go inside the ```for loop``` :)

Comment: you can check the EDIT

Comment: The problem now, is that I have 2 mappings. Bulk creates its own one. I will never finish this!

Comment: Ingesting into ES will generate a mapping for each field *unless* you specify the field mapping types for *each and every* field.

Comment: Will there be a problem if numeric values like: time(ms), TPU_temp, score are mapped automatically as "test" and as "keyword"? Because that is what the BULK api is doing.

Comment: I'd recommend a mapping defined prior to the bulk operation. You surely want your time field to be decimal, not string...

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are trying provide data in String format instead it has to be in Json Object like JsonNode in java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).